# Django and Nginx Docker Containers with AWS ECS Error

Tags: django, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am currently building a project using Terraform and AWS ECS with two containers: Django App and Nginx (to host the static files). Currently it works great; however, I am receiving an error in the logs of Nginx (using CloudWatch Logs) saying,

`CommandError: You must set settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS if DEBUG is False.`

I know this has to do with Django's ALLOWED_HOSTS since my `DEBUG` is set to `False` in the `settings.py` file, but I feel everything should be working as it should. Here is what my `settings.py` has for ALLOWED_HOSTS:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('ALLOWED_HOSTS', '').split()`

From here, I have my task definition file named `container-def.json` to do the job in AWS ECS:

```
[
  {
    "name": "django-app",
    "image": "${django_docker_image}",
    "cpu": 10,
    "memory": 256,
    "memoryReservation": 128,
    "links": [],
    "essential": true,
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 0,
        "containerPort": 8000,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "command": ["gunicorn", "-w", "3", "-b", ":8000", "project.wsgi:application"],
    "environment": [
      {
        "name": "RDS_DB_NAME",
        "value": "${rds_db_name}"
      },
      {
        "name": "RDS_USERNAME",
        "value": "${rds_username}"
      },
      {
        "name": "RDS_PASSWORD",
        "value": "${rds_password}"
      },
      {
        "name": "RDS_PORT",
        "value": "5432"
      },
      {
        "name": "ALLOWED_HOSTS",
        "value": "${allowed_hosts}"
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "containerPath": "/usr/src/app/staticfiles",
        "sourceVolume": "static_volume"
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group" : "/ecs/frontend-container",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-1"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "nginx",
    "image": "${ngnix_docker_image}",
    "essential": true,
    "cpu": 10,
    "memory": 128,
    "links": ["django-app"],
    "portMappings": [
      {
        "hostPort": 0,
        "containerPort": 80,
        "protocol": "tcp"
      }
    ],
    "mountPoints": [
      {
        "containerPath": "/usr/src/app/staticfiles",
        "sourceVolume": "static_volume"
      }
    ],
    "logConfiguration": {
      "logDriver": "awslogs",
      "options": {
        "awslogs-group": "/ecs/nginx",
        "awslogs-region": "us-east-1"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

My `var.tf` file where it is contained is as such:

```
####### Input URL of ALLOWED_HOSTS in Django's settings ############
variable "allowed_hosts" {
  description = "Domain name for allowed hosts"
  default     = ".example.org"
}
```

And lastly where I call all these variables to is in my data template for Terraform:

```
### Here lies the container-definition.json file to input what each container's parameters
### must have.
data "template_file" "ecs-containers" {
    template = file("container-definitions/container-def.json")

    vars = {
        django_docker_image = var.django_docker_image
        ngnix_docker_image  = var.ngnix_docker_image
        rds_db_name         = var.rds_db_name
        rds_username        = var.rds_username
        rds_password        = var.rds_password
        allowed_hosts       = var.allowed_hosts
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any feedback on this. I know I'm ALMOST there to fixing the issue. Thanks all.

Comment: Seems like you're environment variable `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is empty hence why in `settings.py` your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting is just an empty list `[]`. To what have you set `var.allowed_hosts` in TF actually? It needs to be set to the domain you're running your Django application on.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I see what you are saying. I currently have Terraform talking to each other on `ALLOWED_HOSTS` where `setting.py` does not recognize `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. The `container-def.json` file should be calling the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` variable but is not recognizing it. Let me go back and check this out.

Comment: After reviewing my code I'm still unsure why my domain is not working when inputting is as `.example.org`.

Comment: Under which URL are you deploying? Is it really a subdomain of example.org?

Comment: The URL is www.roma-nube.org. That's how I have it.

Comment: Well if you're planning to deploy to `roma-nube.org` then this needs to go into `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` controls what host/domain names the Django site can serve. Can you verify when it's running that `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is set?

Comment: Let me check on this.